# Node amazon s3 putObject upload fails to upload multiple files (only uploads one) but says that it worked

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

So in my routes I have a post which lets me send a multipart post, which then gets saved to a database and sends the pictures attached in the post request to amazon s3. 
Here's my code for the route

```
exports.post = function(req, res){
var pictureNames = [];
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'anonybox'}});
for(key in req.files){
    tp = req.files[key].path;
    fn = req.files[key].name;
    ftype = req.files[key].type;
    pictureUrls.push(fn);
    fs.readFile(tp, function(err, fileBuffer){
        var params = {
            Key: fn,
            Body: fileBuffer,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            ContentType: ftype
        };
        s3Bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log("error" + err);
            }else{
                console.log("worked, data: "+JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
}
    messageObject = {
        message: req.body.message,
        staytime: req.body.staytime,
        picturenames: pictureNames
    };
    var postMessage = new MessageModel(messageObject);
    postMessage.save(function(err, doc){
        if(err || !doc){
            throw 'Error';
        }else{
            console.log("created");
            console.log(doc);
    //        res.json(doc);
        }
    });
```

When I try to send two images in the post request In the console the putObject function returns:

```
    worked, data: {"ETag":"\"24c1d19724ca10f40bc633aa29315931\""}
    worked, data: {"ETag":"\"4201e2a997779c5595dc35925e954191\""}
```

But only one of the files shows up in my bucket on s3, the last file in the req.files object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the aws-sdk It was that the for loop kept running before the first file was read in fs.readfile, the solution is detailed here
[Asynchronously reading and caching multiple files in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618142/asynchronously-reading-and-caching-multiple-files-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with two file uploads, I'm just mentioning it for posterity in case someone has a similiar issue in the future: my image uploads were not embedded in a for-loop, but just sequential calls to s3.putObject().  The first image would show up just fine on page refresh, but the second image upload was appearing to "fail silently" without working. The answer, it turns out, for some reason the first file upload would update the cache, but the second image upload would not update the cache, thus appearing to not work (even though the actual file transfer to s3 was actually working). If you are having an issue, try clearing your cache and see if the fresh upload is actually working but your browser isn't showing it properly.