# Parse JSON while asynchronously reading files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, readfile

I am trying to read a few JSON files and store their results into one array. I have:

```
const files = ['file0.json', 'file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']
```

In order to read all of them and create a resulting array of the files' contents, I do this:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs'
import async from 'async'

const files = ['file0.json', 'file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']

function read(file, callback) {
  readFile(file, 'utf8', callback)
}

async.map(files, read, (err, results) => {
  if (err) throw err

  // parse without needing to map over entire results array?
  results = results.map(file => JSON.parse(file))
  console.log('results', results)
})
```

This post helped me in getting there: [Asynchronously reading and caching multiple files in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618142/asynchronously-reading-and-caching-multiple-files-in-nodejs)

What I'm wondering is how to call `JSON.parse()` in the intermediate step of reading the file instead of having to `map` over the resulting array. And I suppose a clarification on what exactly the `callback` parameter inside the read function is used for, if not just passed in for the sake of calling `readFile` properly.

Comment: can you do something like `readFile(file, 'utf8').then(JSON.parse).then(callback)` ?

Comment: @dandavis let's not insult ts with promises yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps you should move `JSON.parse` in read step then

```
import { readFile } from 'fs'
import async from 'async'

const files = ['file0.json', 'file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']

function read(file, callback) {
  readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    try {
      callback(JSON.parse(data));
    } catch (rejection) {
      return callback(rejection);
    }
  })
}

async.map(files, read, (err, results) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('results', results)
})
```

I'd recommend you to read [this article](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4) to understand the meaning of callback function.

Comment: This does parse the JSON, but there are a couple issues. The actual results end up with in the parameter `err` in the `async.map`'s callback, and the `result` param is undefined. 

Also, only the first file ends up in `results`. If I add a `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` inside the `try`, it prints the `results` from the `async.map` after printing the contents of the first file, and then prints the contents of the remaining files.