# multiple images upload in s3 bucket using nodejs in aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am using AWS lambda function and nodejs. I tried to insert multiple images in s3 bucket. find the below for your reference.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fileType = require('file-type');
var bucket = 'testing';
var s3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var Userid = event['userid'];
    var media = event['media'];

    media.forEach(function(eachrecord){
        var fileBuffer = Buffer.from(eachrecord, 'base64');
        var fileTypeInfo = fileType(fileBuffer);
        var randomstring = require("randomstring");
        var fileName = Userid+'/'+'media/'+`${randomstring.generate()}.${fileTypeInfo.ext}`;
        var ext = fileTypeInfo.ext;

        var params = {
            Body: fileBuffer,
            Key: fileName,
            Bucket: bucket,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: fileTypeInfo.mime
        };
        s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
        if(err)
            {
             callback(err, null);
            }
        else
            {
            let response= {body: JSON.stringify(data.Location)};
            let mediaurl =response.body;
            console.log(mediaurl);
            }
        });
    });
context.succeed('done');    
};
```

In media, I have send multiple base64 encode array value in event. but how to implement forloop concept and media insert array value into s3 bucket?

Comment: Did you try this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662686/uploading-multiple-files-to-aws-s3-using-nodejs ??

Comment: @srinivasy bro in the above solution, they are not using event handler and i have sent media event in array like media : [ base64encode, base64encode, base64encode]. is there any provision like for loop concept

Comment: @srinivasy i tried to forEach conditoin after var media = event['media'], but it was not working

Comment: So for each event do you get a list of files not the name `media`, if yes, then what happens if you iterate over media after `var media = event['media'];` then do same process only change will be `var fileBuffer = Buffer.from(eachRecord, 'base64');`

Comment: @srinivasy bro i have one small query, forEach condition working on aws lambda. becoz var media = event['media']; after i tried using forEach(function(eachreacord){remaining code }) but it was not working.

Comment: Any error that you see ?

Comment: @srinivasy bro i have update code in query using forEach condition, you see the updated code in query. I have executed the above code, get the output 'done' but the images are not inserted into s3 bucket

Comment: check if you're getting any issue here :: `if(err)
            {
             callback(err, null);
            }`

Comment: @srinivasy i am not getting any error in console bro.

Comment: that should be from callback() being called early.. If you're still stuck I can try to provide a solution..