# Uploading multiple small files to s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Our web application create multiple small files (180 kb on average).
We upload those files to a dedicated `ceph` application using s3 protocol.

Our web app is written in `js` using node and `aws-sdk`.
We are creating too many small requests to the ceph, and we were wondering if we could upload multiple files in a single request.

Comment: How about zipping the files and uploading the zip in one go?

Comment: We would like to keep the data separated to small files

Comment: Here is a similar post providing multiple upload using `node aws-sdk` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662686/uploading-multiple-files-to-aws-s3-using-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

AWS SDK does not support multiple file uploads directly. if you really need to do it in a single request, you need to use a backend api to accept multiple files in a multipart request and upload files one by one using the sdk's `putObject` method

Alternatively, you can upload files one at a time from the frontend itself.

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't support multiple uploads in one go. Behind the scenes they're all using `.put(singleObject)`.

I suggest making a buffer that accepts files from all sources and is the only one uploading to the target.

Or making a queue on each source machine.